# 802.1x :how to forge and inject EAP- Logoff frames?

Tags: 802.1x

I am testing the vulnerabilities of the 802.1x protocol, applied on wired network. 
Does anyone know how to forge EAP-Logoff frames and spam them to a particular host?

thanks for the help

Comment: There are several tools/libraries available for crafting/injecting ethernet frames.   If you're familiar with Python, Scapy is the most widely known.

Comment: @user52472 Thank you, I am gonna try that!